# Derivative of $\text{Tr}[B X^T A X^{-1}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Let $A, B, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and assume that $X^{-1}$ exists. Derive $\frac{\partial K}{\partial X}$ where 
$K(X)= \text{Tr}[B X^T A X^{-1}]$

I have tried the following so far ($U = B X^T A X^{-1}, K = \text{Tr}[U]$):

$$
\frac{\partial K}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial K}{\partial U} \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} \\
= \frac{\partial \text{Tr}[U]}{\partial U} \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} \\
=I_n \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} \\
B X^T \frac{\partial A X^{-1}}{\partial X} + A X^{-1} \frac{\partial B X^T}{\partial X}
$$
But now I am lacking the tools to compute the matrix-by-matrix derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The cyclic property allows terms in a trace product to be rearranged in lots of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T &= B:A \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C &= AC^T:B \\
}$$
Write the function using the trace product, 
then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 K &= AX^{-1}B:X   \;= A^TXB^T:X^{-1} \\
dK &= AX^{-1}B:dX + A^TXB^T:dX^{-1} \\
   &= AX^{-1}B:dX - A^TXB^T:X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1} \\
   &= AX^{-1}B:dX - X^{-T}A^TXB^TX^{-T}:dX \\
   &= \Big(AX^{-1}B - X^{-T}A^TXB^TX^{-T}\Big):dX \\
\frac{\partial K}{\partial X}
   &= AX^{-1}B \;-\; X^{-T}A^TXB^TX^{-T} \\
\\
}$$

---

In the above, the differential of $X^{-1}$ was utilized;
here's how it was derived.
$$\eqalign{
I &= X^{-1}X \\
0 &= dX^{-1}X + X^{-1}dX \\
0 &= dX^{-1}  + X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1} \\
dX^{-1} &= -X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1} \\
}$$
As you have discovered, the problem with the chain rule in matrix calculus is that it very often requires the calculation intermediate quantities which are higher-order tensors, e.g. matrix/matrix, matrix/vector, and vector/matrix derivatives.

The differential approach is simpler because the differential of a matrix is just another matrix and obeys the rules of matrix algebra.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Only one more question: In your first step where you go from $K$ to $dK$, where does the "+" come from?

Comment: Because each term in the product must be differentiated independently, e.g. 
$$
d(A\star B\star C) = dA\star B\star C+A\star dB\star C+A\star B\star dC
$$
This is true regardless of the type of product denoted by the $(\star)$ symbol. Some products are distributive or commutative, so they can be rearranged to put the the $dX$ term at the end, as I did in that first step. 

Also, since the differential of a constant matrix is zero, I omitted those terms.